# Split string into associative array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, split, preg-split

#### Example string (html content):

```
some content
<h2>title 1</h2>
<p>more content</p>
<h2>title 2</h2>
rest of the content
```

I need to split this into associative array by the `<h2></h2>`, yet keep all contents of the string.

#### Desired outputs:

```
array(){
  'text1' => 'some content',
  'title1' => 'title 1',
  'text2' => '<p>more content</p>',
  'title2' => 'title 2',
  'text3' => 'rest of the content'
}
```

or

```
array(){
  [0] => {
    'text' => 'some content',
    'title' => 'title 1'
  },
  [1] => {
    'text' => '<p>more content</p>',
    'title' => 'title 2'
  },
  [2] => {
    'text' => 'rest of the content'
  }
}
```

#### What I tried

`preg_split()` with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` almost does the job, but it outputs indexed array. 

I tried using regex, but it fails capturing **text3**:

`(.*?)(<h2.*?<\/h2>)`

Any help or idea is very appreciated.

Comment: Are those linebreaks actual new lines?

Comment: are "some content", "more content" ... only text or html?

Comment: Yes, content is HTML.

Comment: if you are not preferring regex, try with `str_word_count`

Comment: Use a DOM Parser to parse HTML.

Comment: Use this `(?s)(?:<h2>(.*?)</h2>|\s*(.+?)\s*(?=<h2>.*?</h2>|$))` forget that duplicate junk. Parsing html with a DOM will fail if the html is junked up. Use something that works. Or, you could try to find a  DOM parser that can go past malformed html (and you can't).

Comment: @sln Thank you very much! This helped a lot. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it. On the other note, I don't get all the fuss about DOM parsers and stuff, all I need is to split the bloody string, it doesn't matter if it's html or not.

Comment: @MatijaMrkaic - Questions marked as duplicates cannot be answered. And in fact, your question is going into the boneyard never to be seen again. You can petition the admin if you'd like.

Comment: @sln Usually a DOM parser in HTML mode *can* parse incomplete and even malformed HTML. That's the reason why not every second webpage fails to display with "Malformed markup". PHP's DOM parser which is based on libxml2 makes a good job there. A regex can't be used for this kind of tasks, at least it will not work reliably and is hard to maintain. The level of unreliability and un-maintenancy will increase with the complexity of the section to be parsed.

Comment: @hek2mgl - If a DOM parser can go past malformed sgml then what makes it different than a Regular Expression Parser. Seriously, consider this simple looking thing `(?s)<[\w:]+(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+>`. It is probably the most complex regex ever made that parses an html tag malformed or not. This is engine power.

Comment: @sln Sure, a parser internally (likely) also uses regexes to identify tokens. However, a parser is more than a single regex. I really suggest to read the `Flex/Bison` O'Reilly. I'm pretty sure you'll have fun. (I don't say that an SGML parser is built using Bison, however the book is a nice read and explains the concepts very well)

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do a regex split:

```
preg_split ("/<\/?h2>/", sampletext)
```

where sampletext here looks just like your input example. we can assume that every 2 splits is equivalent to one `<h2></h2>` pair, so you can label them according to their array index.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a function real quick, it has only been tested on your content, but maybe it will be helpful for you.

```
<?php
function splitTitlesAndContent($needle1,$needle2,$content){
    $spli = explode($needle1,$content);
    $arr = array();
    $titlenum = 1;
    $contentnum = 1;

    foreach($spli as $spl){
        $expl = explode($needle2,$spl);

        if(isset($expl[1])){
            $arr['title' . $titlenum] = trim($expl[0]);
            $titlenum++;

            $arr['content' . $contentnum] = trim($expl[1]);
            $contentnum++;
        }
        else{
            $arr['content' . $contentnum] = trim($expl[0]);
            $contentnum++;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

$content = 'some content
<h2>title 1</h2>
more content
<h2>title 2</h2>
rest of the content';

$splitted = splitTitlesAndContent('<h2>','</h2>',$content);
print_r($splitted);
?>
```

You can try it out here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e80b68d919c0292e7b52d2069128e21ba1614f4c